# create links dynamically with pyspark from nodes and reference dataframe

Tags: loops, pyspark, nodes

I want to make a new dataframe based on these dataframes:

DF1:

```
| Name  | ID  | Group    |
| ----- | --- | -------- |
| A     | 0   | mgr      |
| B     | 1   | mgr      |
| C     | 2   | mgr      |
| D     | 3   | hr       |
| E     | 4   | hr       |
| F     | 5   | hr       |
| G     | 6   | adm      |
| H     | 7   | adm      |
| I     | 8   | adm      |
```

DF2:

```
| Mgrs  | HR    | Admin    | Value |
| ------| ----- | -------- | ----- |
| A     | D     | G        | .0010 |
| B     | E     | H        | .0002 |
| C     | F     | I        | .0035 |
```

I want to iterate over DF2 by DF1 and produce a new dataframe:

DF3:

```
| From  | To  | Value|
| ----- | --- | -----|
| 0     | 3   | .0010|
| 1     | 4   | .0002|
| 2     | 5   | .0035|
| 3     | 6   | .0010|
| 4     | 7   | .0002| 
| 5     | 8   | .0035|
```

I’m wanting to start at the top of DF1 (A)  to retrieve ID (0), place that in the “From” column in DF3, and then the “To” column key would be the right adjacent column in DF2 (some of DF2’s column headers correspond to the values in the Group column in DF1).  I also want to preserve the Value column into DF3, corresponding to DF2’s rows.   Any suggestions on how to accomplish this with PySpark? I was thinking perhaps a join of some kind might work too.

Comment: Can you explain more about the logic here?

Comment: I made some edits to the explanation, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Why does the last row have value `.0010`? Wouldn't it be `.0035`?

Comment: yep, typo. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, a couple of joins would work here

###### Starting with getting IDs

```
temp = (df2
    .join(df1, on=df1['Name'] == df2['Mgrs'], how='left')
    .select(F.col('ID').alias('Mgrs'), 'HR', 'Admin', 'Value')
 
    .join(df1, on=df1['Name'] == df2['HR'], how='left')
    .select('Mgrs', F.col('ID').alias('HR'), 'Admin', 'Value')
 
    .join(df1, on=df1['Name'] == df2['Admin'], how='left')
    .select('Mgrs', 'HR', F.col('ID').alias('Admin'), 'Value')
)

+----+---+-----+------+
|Mgrs| HR|Admin| Value|
+----+---+-----+------+
|   0|  3|    6| 0.001|
|   1|  4|    7|2.0E-4|
|   2|  5|    8|0.0035|
+----+---+-----+------+
```

###### Then process your mapping logic

```
one = temp.select(F.col('Mgrs').alias('from'), F.col('HR').alias('to'), 'Value')
two = temp.select(F.col('HR').alias('from'), F.col('Admin').alias('to'), 'Value')
one.union(two).show()

+----+---+------+
|from| to| Value|
+----+---+------+
|   0|  3| 0.001|
|   1|  4|2.0E-4|
|   2|  5|0.0035|
|   3|  6| 0.001|
|   4|  7|2.0E-4|
|   5|  8|0.0035|
+----+---+------+
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!